# How to deserialize the ModelStateDictionary manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to handle the validation errors in a filter. The validation response format should be something like:

```
    {
        "message": "Validation errors in your request",
        "errors": {
            "email": [
                  "The Email is required"
                ],
            "Address": [
                  "The Address is required"
                ]
        }
    }
```

In my filter when I tried following:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    }
}
```

The response format generated is:

```
{
    "Email": [
          "The Email is required"
        ],
    "Address": [
          "The Address is required"
        ]
}
```

The `message` property and `errors` envelop are missing. I tried many ways, but it didn't work. e.g.

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var validationErrorResponse = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
                validationErrorResponse["message"] = "The request has validation errors";
                validationErrorResponse["errors"] = context.ModelState;
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(validationErrorResponse);
            }
        }
    }
```

But response contained all the properties of modeldictionary:

```
{
  "message": "The request has validation errors",
  "errors": {
    "Name": {
      "childNodes": null,
      "children": null,
      "key": "Name",
      "subKey": {
        "buffer": "Name",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 4,
        "value": "Name",
        "hasValue": true
      },
      "isContainerNode": false,
      "rawValue": null,
      "attemptedValue": null,
      "errors": [
        {
          "exception": null,
          "errorMessage": "The Name field is required."
        }
      ],
      "validationState": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advantage of ASP.NET Core is that it's open source and you can always look at the code and see what it does ;)

Let's first take a look at the `BadRequestObjectResult` class (source [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/BadRequestObjectResult.cs#L29-L30))

```
public BadRequestObjectResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        : base(new SerializableError(modelState))
{
}
```

As we can see, the override for `ModelStateDictionary` passes the model state into a new class `SerializableError` which is then passed to the base class.

When we look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/SerializableError.cs#L43-L57) of `SerializableError` we see, that it's a wrapper around an `IDictionary<string,object>` which formats the messages nicely.

That being said, here is the code you need to use:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var validationErrorResponse = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            validationErrorResponse["message"] = "The request has validation errors";
            validationErrorResponse["errors"] = new SerializableError(context.ModelState);
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(validationErrorResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

That should work (didn't test).